# MongoDB running on Mac OSX

Tags: mongodb

OS: Mac OSX High Sierra
MongoDB: 3.6.9

Running mongod within a terminal with this command, 'mongod --auth', works fine when I connect with this command, 'mongo -u "user" --authenticationDatabase "admin" -p', and supply the password at the prompt. "user" has the "root" role.

However, running with this command, 'mongod -f /usr/local/etc/mongod.conf', causes login failure with same client command as above.

mongod.conf:

```
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb

security:
  authorization: enabled

net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
```

I would prefer to use the config file method. What gives?

TIA,
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `dbPath` explicitly configured in your config file, but do not pass `--dbpath` when you start `mongod` without the config file. When you omit this option it defaults to `/data/db`. This is where your admin user is stored.

You can either change your config file:

```
storage:
    dbPath: /data/db
```

Or you create a new user in the database stored under `/usr/local/var/mongodb`.

How to create a new user, is described in the official docs: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/